# Matlab functions of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, matlab, mathematical-modeling

So I am writing a function to compute the following equations for an SIR model:

[image]

So here's my code:

```
function xdot = sir(t, params)
global h r q;

xdot = zeros(3,1);
SH = params(1);
IH = params(2);
RH = params(3);

xdot(1) = -h*SH + r*IH + gamma(h,t)*RH; % dSh
xdot(2) = h*SH - r*IH - q*IH; %dIh
xdot(3) = q*IH - gamma(h,t)*RH; %dRh

end
```

And then I would call this function like so:

```
global h r q;
h = 1;
r = 2;
q = 3;
params(1) = 1;
params(2) = 2;
params(3) = 3;
[t x] = ode45('sir',[0:0.01:30],params);
```

But I just don't understand how to write the function component inside of `sir.m`. What i mean is this part:
$$\gamma(h,\tau)$$ that is part of the original equation. How exactly would I write this inside the function file?

Comment: Can you phrase your question differently? You laready have calls to `gamma(h,t)` in your function. Are you asking how to define this function? If so, the answer is the same way you defined `sri` function: the `function` keyword followed by the interface, etc.